# pandas PeriodIndex, select 12 months of data based on last period

Tags: pandas, time-series

I have a large table of data, indexed with periods 2017-4 through 2019-3. What's the best way to get two 12 months of data slices? 
I'm basically trying to find the correct way to select `df['2018-4':'2019-3']` and `df['2017-4':2018-3]` without manually typing in the slices.

Play data:

```
np.random.seed(0)
ind = pd.period_range(start='2017-4', end='2019-3', freq='M')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, (len(ind), 2)), columns=['A', 'B'], index=ind)
df.head()
```

[image]

Comment: You should just be able to do `df['2017-04':'2018-03']`

Comment: Yes, I can do that, but date range is always different. So I need to split it into 2 chunks of 12 months dataframes. Manually typing those in seems like a poor way to solve this.

Comment: Do you have the starting indexes (2017-4, 2018-4) at least?